# Grails - Cannot override the final method

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have created the `RegisterController.groovy` out of the `spring ui package`.

When I created it, it looked like that:

```
class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController{
}
```

Then I just copied the initial `RegisterController.groovy` into my template.

```
package com.testApplication.register

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.dao.NullSaltSource
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegistrationCode
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine


class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {


    // override default value from base class
    static defaultAction = 'index'

    // override default value from base class
    static allowedMethods = [register: 'POST']

    def mailService
    def messageSource
    def saltSource

    def index() {
        def copy = [:] + (flash.chainedParams ?: [:])
        copy.remove 'controller'
        copy.remove 'action'
        [command: new RegisterCommand(copy)]
    }

    def register(RegisterCommand command) {

        if (command.hasErrors()) {
            render view: 'index', model: [command: command]
            return
        }

        String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : command.username
        def user = lookupUserClass().newInstance(email: command.email, username: command.username,
                accountLocked: true, enabled: true)

        RegistrationCode registrationCode = springSecurityUiService.register(user, command.password, salt)
        if (registrationCode == null || registrationCode.hasErrors()) {
            // null means problem creating the user
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.miscError')
            flash.chainedParams = params
            redirect action: 'index'
            return
        }

        String url = generateLink('verifyRegistration', [t: registrationCode.token])

        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        def body = conf.ui.register.emailBody
        if (body.contains('$')) {
            body = evaluate(body, [user: user, url: url])
        }
        mailService.sendMail {
            to command.email
            from conf.ui.register.emailFrom
            subject conf.ui.register.emailSubject
            html body.toString()
        }

        render view: 'index', model: [emailSent: true]
    }

    def verifyRegistration() {

        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        String defaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl

        String token = params.t

        def registrationCode = token ? RegistrationCode.findByToken(token) : null
        if (!registrationCode) {
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.badCode')
            redirect uri: defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        def user
        // TODO to ui service
        RegistrationCode.withTransaction { status ->
            String usernameFieldName = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.usernamePropertyName
            user = lookupUserClass().findWhere((usernameFieldName): registrationCode.username)
            if (!user) {
                return
            }
            user.accountLocked = false
            user.save(flush:true)
            def UserRole = lookupUserRoleClass()
            def Role = lookupRoleClass()
            for (roleName in conf.ui.register.defaultRoleNames) {
                UserRole.create user, Role.findByAuthority(roleName)
            }
            registrationCode.delete()
        }

        if (!user) {
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.badCode')
            redirect uri: defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username

        flash.message = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.complete')
        redirect uri: conf.ui.register.postRegisterUrl ?: defaultTargetUrl
    }

    def forgotPassword() {

        if (!request.post) {
            // show the form
            return
        }

        String username = params.username
        if (!username) {
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.forgotPassword.username.missing')
            redirect action: 'forgotPassword'
            return
        }

        String usernameFieldName = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.usernamePropertyName
        def user = lookupUserClass().findWhere((usernameFieldName): username)
        if (!user) {
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.forgotPassword.user.notFound')
            redirect action: 'forgotPassword'
            return
        }

        def registrationCode = new RegistrationCode(username: user."$usernameFieldName")
        registrationCode.save(flush: true)

        String url = generateLink('resetPassword', [t: registrationCode.token])

        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        def body = conf.ui.forgotPassword.emailBody
        if (body.contains('$')) {
            body = evaluate(body, [user: user, url: url])
        }
        mailService.sendMail {
            to user.email
            from conf.ui.forgotPassword.emailFrom
            subject conf.ui.forgotPassword.emailSubject
            html body.toString()
        }

        [emailSent: true]
    }

    def resetPassword(ResetPasswordCommand command) {

        String token = params.t

        def registrationCode = token ? RegistrationCode.findByToken(token) : null
        if (!registrationCode) {
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.resetPassword.badCode')
            redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        if (!request.post) {
            return [token: token, command: new ResetPasswordCommand()]
        }

        command.username = registrationCode.username
        command.validate()

        if (command.hasErrors()) {
            return [token: token, command: command]
        }

        String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : registrationCode.username
        RegistrationCode.withTransaction { status ->
            String usernameFieldName = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.usernamePropertyName
            def user = lookupUserClass().findWhere((usernameFieldName): registrationCode.username)
            user.password = springSecurityUiService.encodePassword(command.password, salt)
            user.save()
            registrationCode.delete()
        }

        springSecurityService.reauthenticate registrationCode.username

        flash.message = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.resetPassword.success')

        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        String postResetUrl = conf.ui.register.postResetUrl ?: conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        redirect uri: postResetUrl
    }

    protected String generateLink(String action, linkParams) {
        createLink(base: "$request.scheme://$request.serverName:$request.serverPort$request.contextPath",
                controller: 'register', action: action,
                params: linkParams)
    }

    protected String evaluate(s, binding) {
        new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(s).make(binding)
    }

    static final passwordValidator = { String password, command ->
        if (command.username && command.username.equals(password)) {
            return 'command.password.error.username'
        }

        if (!checkPasswordMinLength(password, command) ||
            !checkPasswordMaxLength(password, command) ||
            !checkPasswordRegex(password, command)) {
            return 'command.password.error.strength'
        }
    }

    static boolean checkPasswordMinLength(String password, command) {
        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

        int minLength = conf.ui.password.minLength instanceof Number ? conf.ui.password.minLength : 8

        password && password.length() >= minLength
    }

    static boolean checkPasswordMaxLength(String password, command) {
        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

        int maxLength = conf.ui.password.maxLength instanceof Number ? conf.ui.password.maxLength : 64

        password && password.length() <= maxLength
    }

    static boolean checkPasswordRegex(String password, command) {
        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

        String passValidationRegex = conf.ui.password.validationRegex ?:
                '^.*(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$'

        password && password.matches(passValidationRegex)
    }

    static final password2Validator = { value, command ->
        if (command.password != command.password2) {
            return 'command.password2.error.mismatch'
        }
    }
}

class RegisterCommand {

    String username
    String email
    String password
    String password2

    def grailsApplication

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, validator: { value, command ->
            if (value) {
                def User = command.grailsApplication.getDomainClass(
                    SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName).clazz
                if (User.findByUsername(value)) {
                    return 'registerCommand.username.unique'
                }
            }
        }
        email blank: false, email: true
        password blank: false, validator: RegisterController.passwordValidator
        password2 validator: RegisterController.password2Validator
    }
}

class ResetPasswordCommand {
    String username
    String password
    String password2

    static constraints = {
        password blank: false, validator: RegisterController.passwordValidator
        password2 validator: RegisterController.password2Validator
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error at:

class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {`` ` with the error: ``Cannot override the final method from RegisterController`

and at

`package com.testApplication.register`

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
     referenced from required .class files
    - The type org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced 
     from required .class files
    - The type org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SavedRequest cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
     referenced from required .class files
```

I tried to use `@Override` however, this does not change it. What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Why did you have to copy the code of the class you are extending? You need ONLY the methods you are changing, unchanged methods don't need too be copied at all.

Comment: @GermannArlington Yep thats true! However, I am a beginner to `spring security and ui` and wanted to look through the whole code. However, why do I get this even tough I am just overwritting the subclass!

Comment: Your error message suggests that this method is defined as final (i.e. can not be modified) - I think it reefers to `static final password2Validator` at the end of your `RegisterController` class definition

Comment: @GermannArlington I deleted it, however, nothing changes...

Comment: Did you delete `static final passwordValidator` too? ANYTHING defined as `final` can not be modified. That is the reason why I said that you should NOT have copied the complete source into your class, you can still refer to the original code from the original class any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final keyword prevents you from modifying a class if applied to the class, or a method if applied to a method.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29 :

> A final method cannot be overridden or hidden by subclasses. This is used to prevent unexpected behavior from a subclass altering a method that may be crucial to the function or consistency of the class.

If you subclass a class with a final method you need to leave that method alone. If the class is final you can't subclass it at all.

Comment: Possibly because there are no final methods in the base class, and the OP didn't need a pedantic definition of final in Java/Groovy :)

Comment: Actually the fact that they tried to use the @override annotation to fix a problem with final shows that they probably did... not to mention the question subject saying "cannot override a final method" ;)

Answer (score -1):

Refresh dependencies solved my issue.